# trouble setting NSWindow and UIView BackgroundColor in a loop within a method

Tags: objective-c, loops, uiview, background-color, nswindow

I have great trouble setting background color for NSWindow (Mac OS X) and UIView (iOS) within a method or in a loop. 
    Following code of setting background color only works for the last line of code in loop, which is when all values of i, j, k are 255, as screen turn to white as a proper mixture of RGB.

```
`- (void) ChangeColorLoop
{
for (int i=0; i<=255; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<=255; j++)
        for (int k=0; k<=255; k++)
        {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.1];
            //NSLog(@"%d, %d, %d", i, j, k);
            float red = (float) i/255;
            float green = (float) j/255;
            float blue = (float) k/255;    
            float alpha = 1.0f;
            UIColor *mixedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
            //BackgroundView.backgroundColor = mixedColor;
            [BackgroundView setBackgroundColor:mixedColor];
        }
}`
```

Thanks in advance,

Jerry

Comment: Is this method running on a background thread?

Comment: I don't know, but it suppose a (IBAction) instead of (void) as I posted. So when I click the button, it trigger this method and it will start running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setBackgroundColor:` message is only going to be actioned when your code returns to the event loop, which it doesn't do until the very end. This is why only the last colour "takes."

So, you need to run your loop on a background thread. *But* the `setBackgroundColor:` call needs to be on the main thread (since that's where all UI code goes).

If you use GCD, your logic needs to be something like:

```
-(void)changeColorLoop {
  dispatch_async(backgroundqueue, ^{
    for (;;) {
      // Do stuff
      dispatch_sync(main_queue, ^{
        [BackgroundView setBackgroundColor:mixedColor];
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It works with another 2 lines of code, "dispatch_queue_t main_queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundqueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.app.request", NULL);". Awesome, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from your comment like this is running on the main thread. I see several problems with it. The fundamental reason why you're not seeing the color change is because your loop is blocking the main thread, and views are (normally) only redrawn at the end of a run loop cycle. That doesn't happen until after your entire loop has finished. There are various ways to solve this. The simplest is probably to manually run the run loop each time through your for loop. You could also move this work to a background thread and dispatch the `setBackgroundColor:` call to the main queue. Another way to do this would be to use a timer (either NSTimer or a timer dispatch source) to periodically update the color.

In any case, you shouldn't be sleeping the main thread in the middle of your for loop. There's almost never a good reason to sleep the main thread, and doing so blocks your UI from updating or processing user input events.

EDIT: Here's some sample code showing the timer approach I mentioned:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *colorChangeTimer;
@property (nonatomic) float red;
@property (nonatomic) float green;
@property (nonatomic) float blue;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.red = 0.5;
        self.blue = 0.5;
        self.green = 0.5;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)updateColors:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSColor *newColor = [NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:self.red green:self.green blue:self.blue alpha:1.0];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:newColor];
    if (self.red >= 1.0) {
        [self.colorChangeTimer invalidate];
        self.colorChangeTimer = nil;
    }
    if (self.green > 1.0) {
        self.green = 0.0;
        self.red += 0.01;
    }
    if (self.blue >= 1.0) {
        self.blue = 0.0;
        self.green += 0.01;
    } else {
        self.blue += 0.01;
    }
}

- (IBAction)changeColors:(id)sender 
{
    if (self.colorChangeTimer != nil) return;
    self.colorChangeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateColors:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize colorChangeTimer = _colorChangeTimer;
@synthesize red = _red;
@synthesize green = _green;
@synthesize blue = _blue;

@end
```